# Create a very low specificity css property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a very low specificity css property using javascript. Just like `!unimportant` (*which doesn't exists*)

I don't know whether this is possible or not.

My reason to look for something like `!unimportant` is that I am writing a small javascript plugin. In which I want to add a default style to a element which should be later easily overriden by the user.

But if I write:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

The user will not be able to override the above style easily without using `!important`. So, I added a dynamic style tag by using the following code:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
// WebKit hack :(
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

and then to the above code, I added a dynamic stylesheet using the following code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('main');
// To use attribute names to apply the styles
element.setAttribute('custom-el', '1');

var sheet = style.sheet;
var properties = "background-color: green;";
var elName = "[custom-el]";

if (sheet.insertRule) {
    sheet.insertRule(elName + "{" + properties + "}", 0);
} else if (sheet.addRule) {
    sheet.addRule(elName, properties, 0);
}
```

Now the `background-color: green` can be overriden by using the following code:

```
div.main { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

But as you can see in css, I used higher specificity to override `background-color: green` i.e `div` + `.green`.

But I want the overriden to happen even when user writes the following css:

```
.main{   /* Could be simple class name or id name or even tag name */
     background-color: red;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hxyk7cx4/1/)

This might seems to be a small issue. but it is a big problem for me. Please help.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you fully but how about setting the base style on the `element` (like say `div`)?

Comment: @Harry if I apply styles to `div` tag, then it will apply to all the div elements. which I am not looking for...

Comment: why not use !important on the "overrided" css, then the inline style is overrided

Comment: Why not just have a class but have no styling attached to it?

Comment: @slime that is similar to having a custom attribute.. which I am using in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply write like this:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = element.style.backgroundColor || "green";
```

Where, if `backgroundColor` is undefined then it uses `green` as backgroundColor else it would take the `backgroundColor` from stylesheet.

Comment: lets say `backgroundColor` is undefined. Then the `green` color will be applied to the element which I can't override in css using `.main { background-color: red; }`. To override, I should use `!important` which I don't want to use as I explained in my post.

Comment: I am not able to get that.. please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxyk7cx4/2/).

Comment: Hmmm, it's getting transparent if there is no background-color is defined in css..

Comment: @Nick It's not setting the green as background color because if you don't set in css then it uses transparent....

Comment: @Nick it is not showing `green` color when I remove the css style. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxyk7cx4/4/) I don't know my below solution works but someone downvoted it. maybe it is not ideal solution.

Comment: You might want to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle). If you don't, it will only grab the color attached via the style attribute, not via a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer..

```
document.head.insertBefore(style, document.head.children[0]);
```

I should just insert the dynamic stylesheet above already present stylesheets in the `head` tag.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxyk7cx4/)**

Unfortunately, this is not working in any IE version. I am still looking for answer.